# Prove or Disprove: If a function is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and $|f(x)|\leq |x|^\alpha$ with $\alpha>1$, then $f'(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I believe it's true, but I'm stuck. I think it involves MVT somehow, but we can't say anything about the function in order to conclude that the derivative at a defined point $0$ is equal to zero. I would appreciate any guidance on this, as I have been struggling with it for a long time.

Comment: I suggest you just write down the definition of differentability at $0$ and see what you get. Useful to show first that $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $|f(0)| \leq |0|^\alpha=0$, so $f(0)=0$. Next, if $x \neq 0$, $|f(x)| \leq |x|^\alpha$ implies that $$\bigg| \frac{f(x)}{x} \bigg| \leq |x|^{\alpha-1}.$$

Comment: I'm not quite sure how that helps. It merely seems like a more complex function with more constraints. Is it working its way toward the limit definition of differentiation?

Comment: That' right. Use that $f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. Also, recall that $|z| \leq r$ is the same as $-r \leq z \leq r$.

Comment: So since $f'(0) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \frac{f(x)}{x}$. Since we know $|\frac{f(x)}{x}| \leq |x|^{\alpha-1}$ and we know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} |x|^{\alpha-1} = 0$ we can say that the $|f'(0)|\leq 0$ and therefore $f'(0) = 0$. Is this a valid proof?

Comment: I was thinking in something like: since $\big| \frac{f(x)}x \big| \leq |x|^{\alpha-1}$ is the same as $-|x|^{\alpha-1} \leq \frac{f(x)}x \leq |x|^{\alpha-1}$, the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) tells us that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 0$.

Comment: Ah, well since, $|\frac{f(x)}{x}|$ is in absolute values is it not valid to just conclude that it is bounded below by zero?

Comment: Oh, we want to remove the absolute value symbols. That makes more sense. This was very helpful!